transition when click an Item on Recyclerview
i want a transition when switch activity when click an item in recyclerView like this:
i want transition like this
i trying search google more but i find no info. this my problem to find the key word animation or transition here. can you helpe me ? Thank you.

You can use MotionLayout
official documentation reference: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/motionlayout
here is an example
https://github.com/FarshadTahmasbi/motionlayout-recyclerview
